# Align div contents in the middle

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ho do i display the heading, the description and the form in the middle?

HTML:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column splash">
        <span class="splash-heading">Welcome to PlayMaker</span>
        <span class="splash-description">Choose your city so we can tailor the results to your location</span>
        <div class="city-chooser">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <select id="combobox">
                    <option value="">Start typing...</option>
                    {% for city in cities %}
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.splash-left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.splash-right {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    padding-top:145px;
}

.splash span {
    display: block;

}

.splash-heading {
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding-top: 145px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.splash-description {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: could u set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
.splash{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
display: table;/*force to center*/
}
```

Comment: It moved the image out of place but did not alter the position of the elements

Answer (score 1):

Just use the bootstrap class `text-center`

**Doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-emphasis  =>  alignement area

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122696

**HTML** :

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column splash text-center">  // <---- HERE
        <span class="splash-heading">Welcome to PlayMaker</span>
        <span class="splash-description">Choose your city so we can tailor the results to your location</span>
        <div class="city-chooser">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <select id="combobox">
                    <option value="">Start typing...</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                        <option value="{{ city }}">{{ city }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.splash span {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    width: 100px; /* your width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean? displaying all 3 in the middle of the browser window, if yes then -

- first add a parent div named as `<div class="container">` before your `<div class="row clearfix">`. Like this -

  `<div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
          ---- your other div content here ----
      </div> <!--row-->
   </div> <!--container-->`
- then add bootstrap class 'text-center' next to 'col-md-12' class
- then add following css in your stylesheet:

  `.city-chooser { display: inline-block; width: auto; }`

It should help you.

Answer (score -2):

```
.column.splash{text-align:center; display:block;}
```